# How do I modify a CSS checkbox label to include a 'required' function

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have created a CSS checkbox. It’s based on a CodePen script I've whittled down, but I can't find how to modify it for a "required" checkbox. The best I can do is to change the color of the box-shadow on "hover", but that's as close as I can get.

Here is what I have:

```css
.checkbox1 {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox1 label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #dddddd 80%);
  border: 0.5px solid #7d878d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.checkbox1 label:after {
  opacity: 0.0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6600;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.checkbox1 label::after {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.checkbox1 input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 5;
}

.checkbox2 {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox2 label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #dddddd 80%);
  border: 0.5px solid #7d878d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.checkbox2 label:after {
  opacity: 0.0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6600;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.checkbox2 label::after {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.checkbox2 label:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ff0000;
  opacity: 5;
}

.checkbox2 input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="input1" name="" />
  <label for="input1"></label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="input2" name="" required="" />
  <label for="input2"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: By required, you mean you need some action to stop unless the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I'd like the css checkbox to behave just as a default html "required" checkbox, when you uncheck a checked checkbox. That is to change the box-shadow to red to denonte that this is a required action - the box has to be checked in order to continue. Once the box is re-checked the red of the box-shadow is canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[required]` to select the checkbox that has the `required` attribute, then make your styles based on whether or not it is checked.

I've edited your original code to show this working in the demo below. I've added comments to the CSS to show where I've made the changes.

As you can see, the second checkbox is marked as being "required." Therefore, the `[required]` initial styles (red box shadow) are applied. Once it is checked, the `[required]:checked` styles are applied.

```css
.checkbox1 {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox1 label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #dddddd 80%);
  border: 0.5px solid #7d878d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.checkbox1 label:after {
  opacity: 0.0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6600;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.checkbox1 label::after {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.checkbox1 input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 5;
}

.checkbox2 {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox2 label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #dddddd 80%);
  border: 0.5px solid #7d878d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.checkbox2 label:after {
  opacity: 0.0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #ff6600;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}

.checkbox2 label::after {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

/* Here, we set the default style of an UNCHECKED REQUIRED checkbox */
.checkbox2 input[type="checkbox"][required]+label {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ff0000;
  opacity: 5;
}

/* Now, we set the style of a CHECK REQUIRED checkbox */
.checkbox2 input[type="checkbox"][required]:checked+label {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px transparent !important; /* Remove the box-shadow */
}

.checkbox2 input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="input1" name="" />
  <label for="input1"></label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="input2" name="" required="" />
  <label for="input2"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate the time you have taken to consider and answer my question.
Where I can read up on this type of detailed checkbox ‘required’ styling - to gain a better understanding of css styling. 
Is it possible to modify your script so that the ‘required' checkbox behaves like a default ‘required’ html checkbox: not to display the red box-shadow when first loaded, and only display the red box-shadow when it has been changed from checked to unchecked, or the user tries to continue without checking the ‘required’ checkbox. 
Again thank you in advance.

Comment: @Robert What you want to do wouldn't be possible with pure CSS--you'll need to incorporate JavaScript to watch for when the checkbox is unfocused (a.k.a.: "blurred"). jQuery has a function for this.

Comment: Thank you. I will read about JavaScript and jQuery and let you know how I get on, but it could be a while...

Comment: I’ve found a Javascript which has helped [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_boxshadow.asp)  with  modification I got it to work . But as you see its not the full answer.     <div class="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="input2" name=""/>
  <label for="input2" id="check" onclick="myFunction()"></label>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("check").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 4px 1px #ff0000";
}
</script>
I would like to solve the conundrum. Any further advice, would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.